# need help to find the installed theme in wordpress application @openshift

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I am new to openshift. I have installed rhc on my local[ubuntu].

I have setup my first application in openshift which is of Wordpress. I choose the installation from the openshift console itself. It was not manual.

After installation I loaded my site in browser and logged into the admin panel; where I have installed one new theme.

Now to work on that theme I have cloned the repo into my local machine. But I am not able to find the newly installed theme to work on. So I tried to find that theme via ssh into my application but didn't find the theme there as well. path I am checking is- "/app-root/repo/.openshift/themes"

So where can I find the theme? Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme is saved in your data directory (~/app-root/data), you can see the specific locations of where the files are saved by reviewing this deploy action hook (https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy).

Comment: Just to be confirmed about one thing-

The link suggest when I commit anything with modifications of the theme directory; my commits of the theme will be deployed into the path- .openshift/themes AND the later these will be copied to the application path- /app-root/data/themes directory? Am I correct? Please confirm.

Thank you again.

Comment: yes, that is correct., you should add your theme to your .openshift/themes directory, and it will get deployed to the correct place on your website.